# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy349

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
package com.rest.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.rest.dto.AllotmentRequestDto;
import com.rest.model.FPSStore;
import com.rest.repository.FPSStoreRepository;

@Service
@Log4j
public class UnitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerService {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    FPSStoreRepository fpsStoreRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Scheduled(cron = "30 01 12 ? * *")
    public void unitCardWiseEntitlementCalculation() {

        log.info("<--Starts UnitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerService .unitCardWiseEntitlementCalculation-->");
        try {
            List<Future<AllotmentRequestDto>> list = new ArrayList<Future<AllotmentRequestDto>>();

            List<FPSStore> fpsStoreList = new ArrayList<FPSStore>();
            fpsStoreList.add(fpsStoreRepository.getOne(1l));
            /** to create one executerService for each of the FpsStore */
            ExecutorService executerService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(25);
            for (FPSStore fpsStore : fpsStoreList) {

                UnitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerCallableService unitWiseECSCService = (UnitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerCallableService) applicationContext
                        .getBean("StockAllotmentScheduler1");
                unitWiseECSCService.setFpsStore(fpsStore);
                Future<AllotmentRequestDto> f = executerService
                        .submit(unitWiseECSCService);
                list.add(f);
            }

            for (Future<AllotmentRequestDto> ref : list) {
                ref.get();
            }
            executerService.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("Exception -:", exception);
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info("<--Ends UnitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerService .unitCardWiseEntitlementCalculation-->");
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.omneagate.rest.service;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.rest.dto.AllotmentRequestDto;
import com.rest.model.FPSStore;

@Log4j
@Service("StockAllotmentScheduler1")
@Scope("prototype")
public class UnitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerCallableService implements
        Callable<AllotmentRequestDto> {
    @Setter
    @Getter
    FPSStore fpsStore;

    @Autowired
    UnitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerWrapper unitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerWrapper;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public AllotmentRequestDto call()
            throws Exception {
        log.info("");
        unitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerWrapper
                .calculateCardUnitWiseCalculation(fpsStore);
        return null;
    }

}
```

In the line

```
UnitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerCallableService unitWiseECSCService = (UnitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerCallableService) applicationContext
                            .getBean("StockAllotmentScheduler1");
```

I am getting class cast exception .. 
but while printing the Object it's printing `com.rest.service.UnitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerCallableService@fee68cd` and while print the class i.e 
`unitWiseECSCService.getClass()` it's printing -:class `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy349` and while printing the class name  i.e `unitWiseECSCService.getClass().getName()` it's printing as

```
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy349
```

The help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your maven or gradle build file would be usefull. Usually, class not found are caused by transitive dependencies conflict.

Comment: It is a proxy which is an instanceof `Callable` not of `UnitWiseEntitlementCalculationSchedulerCallableService`. Program to interfaces not concrete classes.

Comment: Hi -DanielLavoie and -M. Deinum Thanks for your help is highly appreciated and I got the solution the problem was @Transactional in call method . again thanks